# Ask for explain of some code of UNIX V6

Tags: location, pdp-11

Currently I am reading the book: Lions_Commentary_on_UNIX_6th_Edition, together I am trying to understand the source code of unix v6, and I found some code intriguing: e.g.

```
. = 40^.
...
. = 60^.
```

This is some PDP-11 assembly which I am not very good at, so could anyone explain to me what did these codes try to do here?
Also, in PDP-11, there is another symbol : "..", can anyone explain what does this symbol do , as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` is the location counter so assembly language statement is adjusting the position of the location counter by the the expressions `40^.` or `60^.` so the intent is to move the assembler location counter around.

If the statement read

```
. = 40 + .
```

it would mean change the location counter to 40 (octal) + the current value of the location counter.   What confuses me is that the `^` is an unary operator that according to the MACRO11 manual I have doesn't make sense in this usage.

Comment: The Lions book is talking about UNIX, so it uses the early UNIX assembly language, which is slightly different from PAL-11 and MACRO-11. See the [UNIX Assembler Reference Manual](http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/ref/as.pdf) by Dennis Ritchie.

Answer (score 2):

The `^` operator returns the value of the first operand and the type of the second.

Hence `.=40^.` sets the location counter to location 40 in the current segment, which I expect would have been data or bss.  A plain `.=40` would try to set the location counter to absolute location 40 which would have been an error, since `as` didn't emit absolute code.

The `..` symbol was the relocation counter, approximately, the location in memory where the program is loaded.  It was a kludge for programs on early PDP-11's without relocation hardware.  As I recall, the only thing anyone ever did with it was to set `..=something` at the beginning of programs that were intended to be loaded at specific locations in core.

You can read the *UNIX Assembler Reference Manual* by Dennis Ritchie [here](http://www.tom-yam.or.jp/2238/ref/as.pdf) in PDF.